# Can I enable framebuffer support in xterm

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, xterm, framebuffer

Can I enable framebuffer support in xterm? If yes, how can I do it? If no, what terminal emulator have a framebuffer support?

Comment: This sounds distinctly like you're going about solving a problem in the wrong way (i.e., the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please back up a step; why do you want framebuffer support in a terminal emulator?

Comment: What do you mean by “framebuffer support”? Do you mean direct access to the GPU? If so, no, because xterm is an X11 application. But Linux already provides a text console on the framebuffer, so what else are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I enable framebuffer support in xterm?

No.  X runs in something parallel to the framebuffer, so they cannot both be used at the same time.